# Span (long text) with image to the right

Tags: html, css

Could you help me with this?
I have a span and an img inside a li in a sidebar. What I want is the span to always have the img to the right and also that the img is vertically centered, no matter how long the text inside the span gets (I dont know how long or short it can gets).

Right now I have this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<li class="sidebar-menu-item">
     <p class="sidebar-menu-button" ><img src="img/logout.png"/>Text that could be very long</p>
</li>
```

What I want:

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flex` on the parent, and `align-items: center` to vertically align it's children.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

li p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<li class="sidebar-menu-item">
     <p class="sidebar-menu-button">Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br>Text that could be very long<br><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png"/></p>
</li>
```

Comment: @Michael did you downvote me for that? IE <= 11 is not a requirement for OP. They selected my answer as the solution to their problem, and would not have if it did not solve their problem. You do know that downvotes are for "this answer is not useful" right? My answer is **definitely useful**. Feel free to comment, but I would think twice before abusing the downvote button on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Michael Are you saying you didn't downvote me? I got the downvote at the same time you commented. And are you kidding me re: "how can it be useful"? Do you go and downvote every flexbox solution on Stack Overflow? It's **obviously useful to OP, which is the point of offering a solution on their post.** Plus, per browser statistic data, there is **97.48% support for flexbox** - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Michael you are being incredibly pedantic. If OP needs to prefix it, they can. Could I add it to my answer? Sure. And I did. But that is no reason to be argumentative about it. *"also, I won't search because I got better things to do, but I'm sure that there are more then 15% IE < 12 users."* If you aren't going to back up your claim, just drop it entirely otherwise it's meaningless.